# Change css of 5 first best match of JQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a search bar with autocomplete using Jquery UI Autocomplete and it works fine. 
What I want to do is to 'HighLight' meaning change css (font,background color etc.) of the 5 first matches in the autocomplete dropdown. So if I have 100 results from a search word I want to show the 5 first much more clear then it is now. I have no idea how to do this, does anyone know who can help me please?

Here is a picture and the code I'm using at the moment.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#search-id').autocomplete({
  source:"search.php",
  minLength:1,
  select:function(event,ui){
  var url = 'assets.php?serial=' + ui.item.serial;
  document.location = url;
},
html:true,
open:function(event,ui){
  $('.ui-autocomplete').css({
    'z-index':'1000',
    'max-height':'200px',
    'overflow-y':'auto',
    'overflow-x':'hidden'
  });
},        
})
 $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
 return $("<li></li>")
   .data("ui-autocomplete", item)
   .append( "<a>" + item.serial + ' | ' + item.type + ' | '
   + item.modell + '<br>' + item.installationsdatum + ' | ' 
   + item.placering +  "</a>" )
   .appendTo(ul);
};
 });
```

Best regards 
Kahin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the autocomplete list items with CSS via:

```
li:nth-child(-n+5) {
    background:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cHN9R/)**